# Priority of dialog (two activities)

Tags: android

After onCreate I've 2 methods:

```
checkFirstTime();
checkVersion();
```

checkFirstTime() open an another activity if app is first time, checkVersion() show a dialog.

Ok, first time open app I see first a second activity and when I press buttons of this (so activity closes) I see dialog (method checkVersion).

I need show always first dialog with changelogs, later second activity.

Any idea?

thanks!

Comment: boolean checkFirstTime() if true checkVersion

Comment: checkVersion show also if is not firstTime (i.e. when there is an update of app)

Comment: why dont you put some boolean value on sahredpreference and check it on checkFirstime() and also call your checkVersion method inside it .